# Jquery: scroll page down 100px from where it currently is

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

How do I animate the page down 100px from where it currently is?

my code doesn't work:

```
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).position().top + 100
    })
```

like this, but without it scrolling the page to a specific element, instead, scrolling 100px from the windows current position:

```
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $("#scrollToHere").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Comment: You can *edit* your questions. Please don't repost them.

Comment: yeah, sorry, tried to delete it but i can't now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollto plugin comes to mind:
http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

but maybe it's a bit overkill for that :)

Answer (score 2):

The scrollTop property tells you where the element is placed from the top. You have to use the window.scrollBy method and the window.scrollY property. Unfortunately you can't use animate on the window.scrollY property since it's read-only.

You should be able to use something like this:

```
function animateScrollBy (x, y, interval) {
    var xpos = 0,
    ypos = 0,
    updateScroll = function () {
        var moveX = xpos <= x ? 1 : 0,
            moveY = ypos <= y ? 1 : 0;

        window.scrollBy(moveX, moveY);
        xpos += 1;
        ypos += 1;
        if (moveX === 0 && moveY === 0) {
            clearInterval(scrollInterval);
        }

    },
    scrollInterval = null;

    scrollInterval = setInterval(updateScroll, interval||1)
}

animateScrollBy(0, 100);
```

The speed is relavant to the amout of pixels moved. I'll try it to update it later.

Comment: hehe first like and first comment, and it's almost a decade. nice code there mate, thank you.