# How to detect if the user has scroll 100px from current position

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a one-page website where I am adding a class while the user clicks on nav. However, if the user has scroll `100px` from the current location the class need to remove.

[DEMO gh pages link](https://santoshah.github.io/testscroll/)

```
//working fine
var scrollvalue = 0;
$('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
     scrollvalue = $(window).scrollTop();
     $(".copyright").addClass("activecopy");
});

  //not working fine
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
          $('.copyright').removeClass('activecopy');
      }
  });
```

Note: I have already read stackoverflow post such as [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883105/jquery-animate-page-down-100px-from-current-screen-position) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883391/jquery-scroll-page-down-100px-from-where-it-currently-is)

Comment: What is the problem you are facing, exactly? From a cursory glance, there appears to be a typo in 'remove' `$('.copyright').remvoeClass('activecopy');` and the line `$(scrollvalue).scrollTop() > 100` should probably be `$(window).scrollTop() > 100`

Comment: The class get remove immediately after I click on nav. It should wait until I scroll `100px`. Thanks, I have updated my code.

Comment: Shouldn't you also be checking how much the user has scrolled from the recorded scroll position (`scrollvalue`) as opposed to the constant value `100`?

Comment: Yes but how do I detect the same ?

Comment: Could you share your HTML ? (The minimum to make a working snippet)

Comment: Pls consider either jquery.inview: https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview or Intersection Observer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API. They might be a lot more performant than your current solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to figure out what exactly the problem is as you have no shared the corresponding HTML markup. Try the following and let me know if it helps.

```
var scrollvalue = 0;
$('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function () {
    scrollvalue = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(".copyright").addClass("activecopy");
});


$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (($(window).scrollTop() - scrollvalue) > 100) {
        $('.copyright').removeClass('activecopy');
    }
});
```

EDIT:

As I said, it's hard to see what's happening because you haven't shared markup. Here is a sample. Hope it helps.

EDIT 2:

To make this generic, you can wrap your code which registers for click listeners and scroll listeners in a function which accepts which elements to operate on as arguments. Sample Below.

```js
function registerScrollTrigger(anchor, target) {
  var $a = $(anchor);
  var $t = $(target);
  $a.click(function() {
    //Get scroll position at the time of the click
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    function handleScroll() {
      // Demo code to show current scroll on the screen
      $t.html('Current Scroll: ' + ($(window).scrollTop() - currentScroll));

      // Check if the user has scrolled 100px since clicking the tag
      if (($(window).scrollTop() - currentScroll) > 100) {

        // Remove active class from element
        $t.removeClass('active');

        // Demo code ti indicate that the scroll to 100px is complete
        $t.html('Complete');

        // Stop listening for scroll events [Optional but recommmended]
        $(window).off('scroll', handleScroll);
      }


    }

    // Add active class to element [Make it blue]
    $t.addClass('active');

    // Listen for scroll event and check if 100px has passed
    $(window).scroll(handleScroll);
  });
}

registerScrollTrigger('#a1', '#scroll1');
registerScrollTrigger('#a2', '#scroll2');
```

```css
div.scroll {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

div.scroll.active {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

div#pad {
  height: 1000px;
}

h4 {
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h4>Scroll Down For the Button</h4>
  <a id="a1" class="js-scroll">Click Me </a>
  <div id="scroll1" class="scroll">
    Start scrolling after clicking the above button
  </div>
   <h4>Scroll Down For Another Button</h4>
  <a id="a2" class="js-scroll">Click Me Too</a>
  <div id="scroll2" class="scroll">
    Start scrolling after clicking the above button
  </div>
  <div id="pad"></div>
```

Note:

You can also do something similar by setting a `data-target` attribute on the anchor which can be used to determine which item to add the class to and remove the class from instead of passing both items as a parameter

Comment: This code not removing class after scroll 100px from current position.

Comment: I have updated my code with a working sample for your reference

Comment: Your code looks good. But that id `#scroll` seems static. I might have multiple navigation point. And each click I want to detect 100px scroll from the current location. I have provided the github link of ghpages.

Comment: Have edited my code to have a generic wrapper which can be called multiple times on multiple elements by passing any jQuery compatible selector or element as arguments

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
       var height = $(window).scrollTop();
       if (height > 100) {
            $(".copyright").addClass("activecopy");
       } else {
          $('.copyright').removeClass('activecopy');
       }


   });
```

I am using this for showing my gototop button in bottom. Hope this will works for you.....